# How do I change the name of the Django "Dosya Seç" button?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLQfR.png)

**strong text**

Hello
I am using ImageField as my Django model. I use the structure in my model as forms. But my problem is, how do I change the text of the "Dosya Seç" button here? Currently, English and Turkish are mixed.
How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I believe this is a setting that comes from your machine. If I'd look at your website it would show `Upload file` as my browser is set to English, maybe you can try changing the language setting of your browser/machine